# Check SVN Access on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been wondering if there's a way to check your svn access on a project. I checkout trunk, then made changes without knowing I don't have an access to commit the file to specific project. This result to "SVN access denied". 
I'd like to know if there's a way to check your access first in trunk, without trying to checkout and commit file.